# how to use PrimeSense Carmine 1.09 in Hydro?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I want to use PrimeSense Carmine 1.09 in Hydro(ubuntu 12.04 64bit), and I have installed OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2, Sensor-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.6.6 and NiTE-Linux-x64-2.2. But when I run this:

roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch depth_registration:=true

I got the error:

No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openni2-camera-0.1.4-0precise-20150515-0513/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.

Please help me and thanks anyway!

And this is the output of lsusb: Bus 002 Device 014: ID 1d27:0609

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213843/how-to-use-primesense-carmine-1.09-in-hydro?/) by [ustbguan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23205/ustbguan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I use the same platform as you. ubuntu12.04 + hydro + primesense 1.09. OpenNI has been installed with ros. When I use "roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch" to get the topics, the problem "No matching device found" appeared. So I searched for the solution and found one that worked out of box. First, you need to download OpenNI2, compile it and install it. The OpenNI2 can be found in https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2.
Then copy the include and lib to the system content.

```
sudo cp -r Include /usr/include/openni2
sudo cp -r Bin/x64-Release/OpenNI2 /usr/lib/
sudo cp Bin/x64-Release/libOpenNI2.* /usr/lib/
```

And then modify the configure file of openni  /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libopenni2.pc. Like this:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include/openni2

Name: OpenNI2
Description: A general purpose driver for all OpenNI cameras.
Version: 2.2.0.0
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Libs: -L${libdir} -lOpenNI2 -L${libdir}/OpenNI2/Drivers -lDummyDevice -lOniFile -lPS1080.so
```

Last, you can test the openni2_launch for you device.

---

Originally posted by [peipei](https://answers.ros.org/users/24968/peipei/) with karma: 26 on 2015-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0